# How to load once (when Tomcat starts) some data (HashMap) to Tomcat's cache?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm working on some Java EE application which has to find some data in HashMap. The problem is that I want to load this HashMap to Tomcat only once - when Tomcat starts and I don't know how to do this. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: Are you sure you want to load your data when tomcat is starting, or when it loads your web application (in case of few web applications it would load some data few times - once for each application)?

Comment: What I really want to is to load HashMap before my web application starts.

Comment: So this HashMap should be used only by one web application?

Comment: That's right. I want to load it once and then search for some data in HashMap many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to load this HashMap only for one web application you can do it when container loads all settings for your app (after it reads `web.xml` file). To do this you can create class which implements `ServletContextListener`.

In its `contextInitialized` method create HashMap you are interested in, and add it as attribute to `ServletContext`. There can be only one `ServletContext` instance for one web application and this instance is available to all servlets/jsp so they can later get that attribute with map you set earlier.

Example:

```
class ContextListenerImpl implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //can be empty for now
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();

        //... here you can create and initialize your HashMap

        //when map is ready add it as attribute to servlet context 
        sc.setAttribute("mySpecialMap", map);
    }
}
```

You can get this map in servlets like

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //...
    Map<Your,Types> map = (Map<Your,Types>) getServletContext()
                                .getAttribute("mySpecialMap");
    //...
}
```

Oh, and one important thing: lets not forget to add this listener to your web application. So you will have to add

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>full.name.of.ContextListenerImpl</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to your `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to load `HashMap` actually before when your web application start.

The [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) is what you want. It will make your code run before the web application is start.